# How can we evaluate solutions of optimization problems with quadratic perturbation?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Assume we have two problems
\begin{align}
x_0 &= \text{argmin}~ f(x)\\
x_1 &= \text{argmin}~ f(x) + (ax-b)^2,
\end{align}
where $f:R\rightarrow R$. It is noted that when $a=0$, these two problems are equivalent. However, for general $a$, can we obtain some bound for $|x_1-x_0|$ with respect to $a$? Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be evaluated by Taylor's approximation.
Without loss of generality, we assume that $f(x)$ is convex, then
\begin{align}
f'(x_0)=0\\
f'(x_1) + 2a(ax_1-b)=0
\end{align}
Since the value of $a$ is small, we let $f'(x_1)\approx f'(x_0) + (x_1-x_0)f''(x_0)$. Then
\begin{align}
f'(x_1) + 2a(ax_1-b)&\approx f'(x_0) + (x_1-x_0)f''(x_0)  + 2a(ax_1-b)\\
&=(x_1-x_0)f''(x_0)  + 2a(ax_1-b)\\
& = 0
\end{align}
Therefore, we can express $x_1$ as
\begin{align}
x_1\approx x_0-\frac{2a^2}{f''(x_0) +2a^2 }x_0 + \frac{2ab}{f''(x_0) +2a^2 }.
\end{align}